# Adding a new column on a data frame depending on another dataframe with a different size

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame in R.

The first one is as follows:

```
Species; Camera; Records
Species A; Cam A; 3
Species B; Cam A; 1
Species A; Cam B; 2
Species B;Cam B; 8
```

and the second is as such:

```
Camera; total records
Cam A; 450
Cam B; 210
```

I would like to add to the first df a column of total records extracted from the second one to end up with a table such as:

```
Species; Cameras; Records; Total Records
Species A; Cam A; 3; 450
Species B; Cam A; 1; 450
Species A; Cam B; 2; 210
Species B; Cam B, 8; 210
```

etc...

I don't think it is hard to do but I cannot find a way to.

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. I suggest you look up 'left_join()' from **dplyr**. For example, `df_final<- left_join(df_1, df_2)` To get a more specific answer it would be better to create a reproducible example, though I suspect yours is a question that is really a duplicate of another that already exists.

Comment: formatted table so it can be read is using read.table(text=.., header=TRUE,sep="; ")

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods for merging dataframes that will do exactly what you want. The `merge` command from base R is very simple in this case:

```
df <- data.frame(Species = c("SpeciesA", "SpeciesB", "SpeciesA", "SpeciesB"), Camera = c("CamA", "CamA", "CamB", "CamB"), Records = c(3, 1, 2, 8))

df2 <- data.frame(Camera = c("CamA", "CamB"), TotalRecords = c(450, 210))

merge(df, df2)

Camera  Species Records TotalRecords
1   CamA SpeciesA       3          450
2   CamA SpeciesB       1          450
3   CamB SpeciesA       2          210
4   CamB SpeciesB       8          210
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr::left_join` function or `merge` function from base R.